# set color bar for all subplots across multiple figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am making geopandas plots (maps) for each month of the year, across a decade of data. One figure per year, with 12 subplots each. I can make the figures fine, but I want to make the Colorbar consistent across all subplots and figures for easy comparison. All the data have different values but all fall within 0 to 10000. I would like to stretch the colors of each map to match this.

so far, I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

# set the filepath and load in a shapefile
fp = 'Senegal_Grid__all_WGS84.gpkg'
map_df = gpd.read_file(fp, layer="Senegal_Grid__all_WGS84")

# shp for clipping the map_df
Senegal = 'sen_admbnda_adm0_1m_gov_ocha_20190426.shp'

Sen_df = gpd.read_file(Senegal)

map_df = gpd.clip(map_df, Sen_df)

years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

for year in years:
    print(year)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=2, figsize=(2.5,6.5))

    ax1 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[0, 0], column='modis_jan_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax2 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[1, 0], column='modis_feb_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax3 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[2,0], column='modis_mar_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax4 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[3,0], column='modis_apr_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax5 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[4,0], column='modis_may_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax6 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[5,0], column='modis_jun_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax7 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[0,1], column='modis_jul_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax8 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[1,1], column='modis_aug_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax9 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[2,1], column='modis_sep_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax10 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[3,1], column='modis_oct_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax11 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[4,1], column='modis_nov_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)
    ax12 = map_df.plot(ax=axes[5,1], column='modis_dec_mean_' + str(year), cmap = "viridis", linewidth=0.1)

    im = plt.gca().get_children()[0]
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.05,0.8,0.03])

    cmap = matplotlib.cm.viridis
    bounds = [0, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000]
    norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

    fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal', ticks=bounds, norm=norm, spacing='uniform')

    plt.title(str(year) + ' MODIS NDVI')
    plt.savefig('modis_NDVI_' + str(year) + '.png', format='PNG')
    plt.clf()
```

This gets me 10 maps that look like this:

[image]

[image]

but the scale is different from figure to figure (see Colorbar in attached figs). I'd like to fix the Colorbar so all the 10 figures can be compared more easily.

How do I set the scale across subplots AND figures?

Comment: You need to provide your common norm also to the plot function (probably `map_df.plot(..., norm=norm)` supposing you create the norm before calling the plot functions).  If `map_df.plot` doesn't accept the norm as parameter, you could explicitly set  `map_df.plot(..., vmin=0, vmax=10000)` .

Comment: Ah, that's it. I did look up the mpl.plot function but couldn't see the arguments. Obviously it was in the geopandas docs: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html